# Comparing 2 Columns in Excel 2013

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

```
A1: 1   B1: C1: 3
A2: 2   B2: C2: 5
A3: 3   B3: C3: 8
A4: 4   B4: C4: 2
A5: 5   B5: C5: 0
```

> `Formula: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$5,0)),"",A1)`

I am trying to compare 2 columns but I am not able to get compare with this formula. Is anyone there who can help me out of this.

Comment: I ran the formula and got B2: 2, B3: 3, B5: 5. I'm also running libreoffice but it should be the same in excel. Is that what you expected as a result?

Comment: What is the desired result ?

Comment: I am getting answer as 0 and its not filling as it has filled in your B Column

Comment: Johnathon Havens can you please send me a snapshot or mail me the workbook you have worked out??

Answer (score 0):

try this and click upvote if it helped. 
u cud simply use this formula: =INDEX(B1:B5,MATCH(A1,C1:C5,0)) kindly know if it helps!

Comment: if data is not available, then of course you will get the #N/A error. you can avoid this by using iferror(INDEX(B1:B5,MATCH(A1,C1:C5,0)),"")

Comment: Comeon why will I try with the empty data i have tried using data bt null values

Comment: Dear Jain, better if u cud post actual data!

Comment: can you send me your email id i ll send you on your id.